# Plugged sata power into vga power output. No video now

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I had just gotten an SSD which I was trying to plug into the PSU(EVGA supernova g3 750 watt) and the motherboard. I didn't remember the layout of the PSU power outs so I accidentally plugged the power cable into the VGA power out of the PSU. The PC started up thrice and shut down immediately. I assumed I was shorting something or had loose connections. The next time, the PC started up but there seems to be no power going to the Graphics card(RX 580 Nitro+). The fans are spinning but the logo is not lighting up and I don't have video.  Mouse and keyboard are also not powered. Ethernet port is powered and shows up on the router but does not light up.

I've tried starting the PC with only the CPU, motherboard and the cooler powered but I'm getting no error beeps.

Did I kill my PSU?

Answer (score 0):

Oh the joys of a modular power-supply...

If I understand you correctly you put the power-cable for the SSD in one of the PSU outlets intended to provide a video-card with extra power.
Depending on the exact way the PSU is internally wired and in which orientation you inserted that plug in the wrong socket you will most likely have fried the PSU and possibly also the SSD.
If you are really unlucky you may also have damaged the motherboard.

That is an expensive mistake to make. Always double-check your wiring before switching on the power.

You will have to test the motherboard (and SSD) using another power-supply.
Personally I wouldn't even attempt to try this PSU with a different motherboard as it could be so damaged it could possibly fry that motherboard too.
So I would consider the PSU a loss and hope the motherboard and SSD are OK.

Comment: From what I can see everything connected to the PSU turns on. Even the gpu fans turn on after I connect the 6 and 6+2 pin power cables to it. Everything connected to it seems to turn on. Could I have just a damaged motherboard on my hands?

Comment: @EdisonMaxwell You can’t tell on basis of that. Could be the motherboard got bad, but it is just as likely the power-on logic or the 5V or 3.3V from the PSU is bad. The fans just need 12V but the motherboard is a lot more complicated. Without a 2nd PSU you can’t tell.

Comment: Its working again. All the components are drawing all the power they need, the SSD is working and my GPU overclocks are as stable as before. I had removed the CMOS battery for 20 minutes, tried booting and it booted properly. I'm not sure why.